# Cannot read the array property. Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a tutorial exercise and I got the following error

*Objects are not valid as a React child*

I know this error is related to the object as I am trying to access the object but it needs an individual item of an object but not sure.

Why cannot the `map` loop over each item in the array?

Following is my code

```js
var template = <h1>Indecision App</h1>;
var app = {
    title: 'Indecision App',
    subtitle: 'yo',
    options: []
}
let count = 0;
function checkSubtitles (subtitle){
    if(subtitle){
        return <p>{subtitle}</p>
    }else{
        return undefined
    }
}
function reset(){
    count = 0;
    reRenderApp();
}
function increaseCount(){
    count++;
    reRenderApp();
}
function onSubmitHandle(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const options = e.target.elements.options;
    app.options.push(options);
    reRenderApp();
    e.target.elements.options.value = ''
}
function removeAll(){
    app.options = [];
    reRenderApp();
}
function reRenderApp(){
    var templateTwo = (
        <div>
            <h1>{app.title}</h1>
            {checkSubtitles(app.subtitle)}
            <p>Count: {count}</p>
            <p>Array Length: {app.options.length > 0 ? app.options.length : '0 Items'}</p>
            <ol>
                {app.options.map((item)=>{
                    return <li key={item}>{item}</li>
                })}
            </ol>
            <hr></hr>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandle}>
                <input type="text" name="options" />
                <input type="submit" value="Push to the Array" />
                <input type="reset" value="Empty my list" onClick={removeAll} />
            </form>
            <button onClick={()=>{
                increaseCount();
            }}>Increase Count</button>
            <button onClick={()=>{
               reset();
            }}>Reset Count</button>
        </div>
    )
    ReactDOM.render(templateTwo, appRoot)
}
var appRoot = document.getElementById('app');
reRenderApp();
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you keep re-rendering it? Just render it once as a component

Comment: @Jacob Following the tutorial, it assumes to teach BTS how to react works so following it as it is.

Comment: `e.target.elements.options` is an `HTMLInputElement`, not a string. Use `e.target.elements.options.value` to get the value of the input.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you so much, the `.value` was hinted below when I was setting it back to empty but was too focused on why it broke. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is, as you mentioned: Objects are not valid as a React child

But, what is happening?

If we go into:

```js
function onSubmitHandle(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // Line 1
  const options = e.target.elements.options;
  app.options.push(options);
  reRenderApp();
  // Line 2
  e.target.elements.options.value = ''
}
```

So in Line 1, you're pushing options into the options array.

But, then in Line 2, we can notice options has an attribute (so, it's an object)

So, if you change Line 1, from:

```js
 const options = e.target.elements.options;
```

To this:

```js
const options = e.target.elements.options.value;
```

It'd work.

Also, to check what I'm saying you have 2 options:

**option 1:** `console.log`

```js
function onSubmitHandle(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const options = e.target.elements.options;
console.log({ options })
  app.options.push(options);
  reRenderApp();
  e.target.elements.options.value = ''
}
```

**option 2:** make that option a valid child of react with `JSON.stringify()`

```html
<ol>
  {app.options.map((item, index)=>{
    return <li key={index}>{JSON.stringify(item)}</li>
  })}
</ol>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, I have more questions now (sorry), 1. Why did you destructure options in your option 1 example, then why use `stringify` in option 2

Comment: When I do `console.log({options})` while `const options = e.target.elements.options;` I get same error as before, meaning it is expecting a value not a HTMLInputElement.

Comment: If you mean this: `console.log({ options })`. It's not a destructure. It's a shorthand for JSON in ecmascript. It'd be like defining an object with attribute 'options', and value options. You can read more about shorthand in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer. My bad, if it didn't work. In that case, you would have to stringify too. Basically, `JSON.stringify` transform an object into a string. And React allow you to print strings in nodes or renders. So, even when it's not the result it'd help you in option 1 and option 2 to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
{app.options.length && app.options.map((item)=>{
                return <li key={item}>{item}</li>
            })}
```

But you must be sure that "item" here is not an object as you can't render an object

Comment: The problem is that `item` is an object; an `HTMLInputElement`. The code the OP has already works, if the items are not objects. The question is why are there objects in the array.

Comment: would you paste the link of the tutorial you're following please?

Comment: If you're trying to ask the OP, the comment should be on the question. If you're asking me, I'm not following a tutorial, I'm just commenting on why this answer does not answer the question.

Comment: @AgustinNuñez its [link](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-2nd-edition/learn/lecture/7707654#overview)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that your options array is going to be filled with elements as you're pushing the input element with the name of "option" into your array - this elements are objects in JS which you can't render out as list items.

- Use React State to store anything that's going to change in the UI - in this case your list of options> So rather than doing

  var app = {
  title: 'Indecision App',
  subtitle: 'yo',
  options: []
  }

  let count = 0;

Do:

```
const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
```

Title and subtitle are probably not going to change, so just put them in h1 & h2 elements - if they are, then use the state pattern again.

Get rid of the two inputs with types of "submit" & "reset" just use normal button elements instead.

You'll also need an onchange event on your input where the text will go in and each time the onchange event is fired (i.e, when a user types) you'll need to save the input text

```
const [inputText, setInputText] = React.useState('');

const handleChange = (e) => {
    const {value} = e.target;
    setInputText(value)
}

<input type="text" value={inputText} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

Then in your onHandleSubmit function, just have

```
const onHandleSubmit = () => {
    setOptions([...options, inputText]);
    setInputText('')
}
```

This should work